# How to locate, using Xpath, an input field without using its id

Tags: xpath, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I'm working with a web page with the following HTML where I want to identify the first `<input>` field inside the `<span>` using a text_field from within a page-object.

```
<div id="131:">  Please enter your name:
<span class="autocompspan " style="position:static;">
    <input style="position: static;" class="autocompinput yui-ac-input" id="132:" name="132:" 
    onfocus="juic.fire(&quot;132:&quot;,&quot;_focus&quot;,event);" 
    onchange="juic.fire(&quot;132:&quot;,&quot;_despatchChange&quot;,event);" 
    onblur="juic.fire(&quot;132:&quot;,&quot;_blur&quot;,event);" size="60" 
    onkeydown="juic.fire(&quot;132:&quot;,&quot;_onkeydown&quot;,event);" 
    onkeyup="juic.fire(&quot;132:&quot;,&quot;_onkeyup&quot;,event);" aria-disabled="false" value="" 
    role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="132:_divList" 
    aria-activedescendant="132:_divAD" findtype="proxy" delimchar="" hideusername="false" 
    fetchusername="false" autocomplete="off" type="text">
    <input value="" id="132:_hidden" name="132:_hidden" type="hidden">
</span>
</div>
```

If I use `:id => '132:'` to identify the field things work fine. I.e. `text_field(:target_user_name, :id => '132:' )`  works.

The issue is that this HTML is generated by the underlying app (SAP) which does not always generated the same value for the `<input>` field `id` so using the `id` cannot be relied upon to consistently identify the element.
So, given the above HTML what other ways might I go about reliably finding this `<input>` field.

I've tried the following, none of which work. Most of them time out waiting for the element to be located.

```
text_field(:target_user_name, :xpath => "//*[@class='autocompinput yui-ac-input' and @role = 'combobox']" )
text_field(:target_user_name, :xpath => "//*[@class='autocompinput' and @role = 'combobox']" )
text_field(:target_user_name, :xpath => "//span/input[@class='autocompinput yui-ac-input' and @role = 'combobox']" )
text_field(:target_user_name, :xpath => "//input[@class='autocompinput yui-ac-input' and @role = 'combobox']" )
text_field(:target_user_name, :class => 'autocompinput yui-ac-input')
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: As a user, how would you identify the text field? There is likely some user visible text that lets a user know what this text field is for. I would use that text and its relationship to this field to do the identification.

Comment: There is a div with some field label surrounding the span which surrounds the input.

Comment: Re the above comment - What would and XPATH look like that would find the input field in that case? Would have thought the XPATHS where I anded the input field attributes would work.

Comment: it would depend on exactly what that HTML is. XPath is very dependent on the structure of the HTML, so it would help if you could expand your HTML snippet to include that outer div.

Comment: Just updated the snippet to show the outer div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an element does not have unique identifiable attributes, you should look at the elements around it. In this case, there is user visible text that helps a user identify the purpose of the field. That same text can be used to identify the element in Watir.

As the surrounding `div` only contains the labelling text, you can search for that `div` by its text and get the only text field in it:

```
browser.div(text: 'Please enter your name:').text_field
```

As a page-object accessor:

```
text_field(:target_user_name) { div_element(text: 'Please enter your name:').text_field_element }
```

Comment: Thanks Justin I'll give that a try this evening. For consistency I'm trying to exclusively use the page-object helpers and not browser.element calls if possible. Is there a way of using the text_field helper to accomplish this. If not then I'll use browser.div

Comment: Yes, you can do similar in the accessor by defining a block. An example has been added.

Comment: Hmmm - that still doesn't find, in this case, the div. I search using "browser.div(text: 'Please enter target user name:').text_field" and get the message "timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for {:text=>"Please enter target user name:", :tag_name=>"div"} to be located (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)". 'Please enter target user name:' is the actual text of the div similar to my example in the original post.

Comment: That's interesting. It works with a page that just contains the provided HTML. What do you get when you output `browser.div(id: '131:').text` (modified for the automatically generated ID at the time)? I'm wondering if there is some other text in the div that is causing the exact text match to fail.

Comment: I changed the text being searched for to use a regex, i.e. /Please enter target user name:/ and it works. So there's probably a newline or something in the div text

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Watir is designed to make it so that you shouldn't have to use XPATH.

It depends on how many different elements/ids are on the page, but I've found that using regular expressions often works well with dynamically generated ids. So either grab the id and use it elsewhere:

```
id = browser.text_field(id: /\d\d\d/).tr(':', '')
```

or just use it directly:

```
text_field(:target_user_name, id: /\d\d\d:/)
```

Comment: I was hoping not to have to use XPATH but can't find a way around it. I considered using a regex but there are 32 fields which match the ** id=\'\d\d\d:\"** pattern. I would have though one of the XPATHs I tried that anded together attributes of the input element would work ... but they don't

Comment: And there are a bunch of different id #s, not just things added to the #s (like `132:_hidden`)?

Comment: The are 75 ids whose value starts with 3 digits followed by a colon. 32 of those are just 3 digits followed by a colon. The other 43 have other text following the colon.

Comment: Can you provide a complete page, I might be able to help with unique locators that aren't too brittle

Comment: The whole page is approximately 450+ lines long so would rather not post. Just updated the snippet to show the surrounding div. Though my question still is why can't I find the input field using, for example, the 3rd item in my list of attempts. It works if I go into the dev tools in Chrome and do an XPath search. Thanks.

Comment: @BobL, on a page with just the HTML you provided, 4/5 of the XPaths you tried do work. If they aren't working on the full page, there is likely an interaction occurring with other elements. Given the size of the page and how generic the class/roles are, you might be matching multiple elements, with the first one not being the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you can check the first input field after 'Please enter your name:' text using below xpath:

```
//div[text()='Please enter your name:']//following::input[1]
```

In general if you encounter fields that does not have a unique identifier you can rely on static text or fields and then use xpath functions such as following, preceding etc.

Comment: Thanks, will try this out. How would I find the first button after this text field whose text is "OK"? Would I use //following::button[text()='OK']

Comment: I meant - How would I find the first button after this **div** field whose text is "OK"? Would I use //following::button[text()='OK']

Comment: Yes you can definitely use this but just make sure you give a try to a unique identifiers such as id, name etc. if available before using xpath functions.

Comment: There is a unique id on the input field but it's dynamically generated by the underlying system and is not guaranteed to be the same between executions.

Comment: Okay. You can use xpath functions in that case.